# Критичны ли повторения?

Tags: плеоназм

Предложение не хочется упрощать, однако двойной повтор "голода" и "животное" режет глаз. Можно ли всё оставить как есть?

"Как животному лучше всего удаётся показать свою животную натуру, когда оно испытывает голод или ощущает опасность, так и я мало чем начинал отличаться от зверя, стоило моему духовному голоду взять надо мной верх".

Answer (score 1):

Я полагаю, что редактирование необходимо, повтор заметен. Вариант правки:

*Как животное более всего проявляет свою **природу**, испытывая гОлод и ощущая опасность, так и я мало чем  отличался от зверя, стоило только **голоду духОвному** взять  верх надо мной.*

Здесь повторяется слово «голод», но в сочетании «голоду духОвному» повтор менее заметен  при смещении логического ударения.

Comment: Спасибо. Как идея: "Как животное более всего проявляет свою природу, испытывая голод и ощущая опасность, так и я мало чем отличался от зверя, стоило только **жажде до всего духовного** взять верх надо мной".

Comment: Как вариант, конечно,  можно использовать. Я тоже искала синонимы и видела  "жажду", но мне оно не приглянулось.  Почему-то не нравится  его звучание (мое субъективное ощущение).  А  объективно – фраза усложняется, не хотелось бы этого.  Я, кстати, часто использую  в текстах этот прием  перестановки (духовный голод и голод духовный).  И он сглаживает повтор, так что кажется, что это даже усиление, а не повтор.

Comment: Хорошо. Оставлю ваш вариант. Тоже скептически отношусь к к "жажде" 

Comment: Прекрасно! А то я думала, что только мне это слово не нравится. Очень много там шипящих, перетягивают на себя внимание.